# Add changes to HTML sections using JavaScript condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, sections

I have a one section website that shows sections (about, services, …) when scrolling down (hiding the previous section).
How can I use JavaScript code to add CSS changes when each section is shown (changes like: show/hide a certain logo, change color of active text of the section in main menu, changing color of navigation menu, …?
What I mean : if this section is selected (using the menu or the nav bar) / scrolled to (mouse scrolling) , then do the CSS changes
Any help?

Similar website: https://bratsun.com/#hello

Answer (score 0):

You could watch the elements if one is in viewport.
This might help: [How can I tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

If the element is in viewport then you add a class (e.g. "active") to the according nav item

Answer (score 0):

A demo web view to scroll down and up folloing the header menu. The page is not reponsive but you can get it as example to set up a better one.

As you can see the `function goToSectionPage` is responsable to do the event to get the scroll to the wish section.

Also, you can optimize the repetition of `function addEventHandlerToHeaderButton` in the js code.

```js
function goToSectionPage(sectionElement) {
  sectionElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center" });
}

function addEventHandlerToHeaderButton(buttonId, sectionId) {
  const buttonTarget = document.getElementById(buttonId);

  buttonTarget.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const parentSectionElement = document.querySelector("main");
    const targetSection = document.getElementById(sectionId);

    goToSectionPage(targetSection);
    addCssClassToSelecedtSession(parentSectionElement, targetSection, "selected");    
  });
}

function addCssClassToSelecedtSession(parentWrapSectionElements, selectedSectionElement, className) {
  for(let section of parentWrapSectionElements.children){
    section.classList.remove(className)
  }
  selectedSectionElement.classList.add(className)
}

addEventHandlerToHeaderButton("headerSection1", "section1");
addEventHandlerToHeaderButton("headerSection2", "section2");
addEventHandlerToHeaderButton("headerSection3", "section3");
addEventHandlerToHeaderButton("headerSection4", "section4");
addEventHandlerToHeaderButton("headerSection5", "section5");
addEventHandlerToHeaderButton("headerSection6", "section6");
addEventHandlerToHeaderButton("headerSection7", "section7");
addEventHandlerToHeaderButton("headerAbout", "about");
```

```css
.section {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.header-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 8px;
    font-family: system-ui;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #00000080;
}

.header-item:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

main {
    padding-top: 45px;
}

.selected {
    animation: sectionSelected 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes sectionSelected {
    from {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #c4c4c4;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stackoverflow.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <span id="headerSection1" class="header-item">Go to Section 1</span>
      <span id="headerSection2" class="header-item">Go to Section 2</span>
      <span id="headerSection3" class="header-item">Go to Section 3</span>
      <span id="headerSection4" class="header-item">Go to Section 4</span>
      <span id="headerSection5" class="header-item">Go to Section 5</span>
      <span id="headerSection6" class="header-item">Go to Section 6</span>
      <span id="headerSection7" class="header-item">Go to Section 7</span>
      <span id="headerAbout" class="header-item">Go to About</span>
    </header>

    <main>
      <section id="section1" class="section">Section1</section>
      <section id="section2" class="section">Section2</section>
      <section id="section3" class="section">Section3</section>
      <section id="section4" class="section">Section4</section>
      <section id="section5" class="section">Section5</section>
      <section id="section6" class="section">Section6</section>
      <section id="section7" class="section">Section7</section>
      <section id="about" class="section">About</section>
    </main>
  </body>
  <script src="./stackoverflow.js"></script>
</html>
```

https://github.com/stembrino/simple-page-example-scroll-down-up

Comment: Great thank you, it's about scrolling, my website is finished and working good from scrolling part, but still have the style problem. I want to do CSS changes when a certain section is Selected (using menu) or Scrolled to, like changing the logo, coloring the active text in the menu, ...

Comment: Ok @FadiKh I changed the code in order to apply some style in the section. We can do that with js. But be aware that the more we apply code the more we must organize. In this case it's just an example, but can be applyed in some separeted part of a project.

Comment: I uploaded a test you can check here to zip file github.com/MDwaihi/Test.git
What I wanted is done when you click to navigate, switching sections using the menu bar or the scrolling icon, the problem still when switching using scrolling, you can see if you check

Comment: I'll create the project in github without zip and add you. So we can apply changes to this project together

Comment: I'm scrolling down and the web site is changing. I didn't understand what you'd like to do

Comment: Hey, sorry that it's not clear for you. If you click "services" from the menu, you go to this section, and you can see the logo and the colors in the menu was changed, this works with me, the problem is while scrolling down with the mouse and not by clicking, still don't know how to do that, also by scrolling I want to change the styles.

Comment: OK I see that the logo was no changed when scroll but works clicking. I update the git project to change the colors. I create a custom libreary to slider to include two function and keep the original file if needed. Please see all commits to realize what was done: https://github.com/stembrino/Vertex   And if you don't mind could u put the arrow up to increase my reputation here in stack

Comment: You can verify here: https://stembrino.github.io/Vertex/

Comment: Great. It works for the logo. But is there a way to change the colors of the text in the menu bar? Example: if it's home (about) page, "about" should be orange and "services" should be black; it it's "services" page, "services" should be orange and "about" should be white.
And please, last question, if two sections were added, what should I do? cause the changes are only for firstSlide and lastSlide

Comment: I want to add two sections after services, the third has the same style we already added as the "about", and the fourth has the same as "services"

Comment: In other way, we can now copy/paste the two existing sections.

Comment: Hello I fixed the section bar. You can see the last version: https://stembrino.github.io/Vertex/

Comment: I can't do more because I have to study the framework that you are using and I worked a lot in this project already and I'm working in a companny as well. I can try it in the future. You can read the code that was changed in the gitHub.

Comment: As I said, please just click in "answer is useful", to do so, click in the UP ARROW in my answer of your question to help me increase profile in stackoverflow. I think it's fair! But if you not want it....ok man, go on.....

Comment: Okay. I did this in your answer.

Comment: Hello again Fabio, please last thing, you can check the solution in GitHub updated by me, I made some changes and fixed everything I wanted. Still one problem (switching colors) in the left navigation menu, please if you can check it. Last issue.

Comment: Yes, for sure. In github we can continue with the process to increse your solututions...I'll comment your commits

Comment: Yes please, it's finished still this issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`IntersectionObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Here's an [educational youtube video on `IntersectionObserver` V1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kW_atFXMG98).

For some corner cases [`IntersectionObserver` V2](https://web.dev/intersectionobserver-v2/) has been specified and implemented in Chrome.